# Flyway and spring integration

Tags: spring, flyway

How do I properly configure flyway when integrating with Spring? I see there is a configure method that takes properties, but from the spring XML it would take a setter method to provide a way to inject a Properties instance.

I could write my own Pojo to delegate the configuration to the flyway instance, but it somehow feels like I have missed something.

Here is my configuration:

```
<bean 
  id="flyway" 
  class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" 
  init-method="migrate" 
  lazy-init="false"
  depends-on="dataSource"
  >
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   <property name="locations" value="classpath:/META-INF/migrations" />
</bean>
```

I would like to provide a dedicated property file for the migration configuration as documented here:

[https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-commandline/src/main/assembly/flyway.properties](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/source/browse/flyway-commandline/src/main/assembly/flyway.properties)

From the [javadoc](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/javadoc/com/googlecode/flyway/core/Flyway.html) I see that I can set most of the properties. I could work with spring ${} property replacements and loading the property file with the built in mechs, but this would make those properties available to all beans, and I would add each one I need.

My wrapper would provide a setter so I could add the following to my spring xml config:

```
<property name="configLocations" value="classpath:/META-INF/flyway.properties" />
```

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Spring's [MethodInvokingFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html) should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can create a migration based on `JdbcTemplate` using Flyway's [SpringJdbcMigration](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/javadoc/com/googlecode/flyway/core/api/migration/spring/SpringJdbcMigration.html). The following example is copied from the [Flyway documentation](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/java.html):

```
import com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.migration.spring.SpringJdbcMigration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class V1_2__Another_user implements SpringJdbcMigration {

    @Override
    public void migrate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) throws Exception {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO test_user (name) VALUES ('Obelix')");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use spring annotation and wrap Flyway class, and do whatever you want. For instance, configuring flyway properties. This blog post may give you an example how to do http://esofthead.com/migrate-database-highly-change-environment-multiple-versions-management/